# how to query firestore collection from the reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**blogs collection**

- content
- title
- slug

**comments collection**

- name
- comment
- email
- status
- blog_id (reference to blog collection. saved as `blogs/auto-id`)

these are my collections. my query is to get all the comments that has the same blog_id. I tried the following query but it did not returned an empty array.

```
comment = firebase.firestore().collection('comments')
doc = 'blogs/'+auto-id
comments.where('blog_id', '==', doc)
.where('status', '==', true)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
   //this return a empty array
   console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
 })
```

Any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it will compile.

Comment: please consider this code as sudo code. thank you.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to post the *actual* code, so there is no misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you make an additional query for

```
.where('status', '==', true)
```

.. but since there are no status fields on the comment collections you display, it is not a match?

Comment: actually there is status field in the comment I just forgot mention I'm so sorry! but thank you for your answer.